# Angular8 Ivy enabled: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'." after re-compilation on any file saving

Tags: angular8

It is Ivy enabled project, while serving first time there are no error, after modifying some html template getting error "core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'." after re-complation due to saving any file.

Comment: Looks like your angular was not building at that time HTML renders. Hence, it is saying Template error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, It is ivy enabled, could you please share your thought now